# Reading/Writing to a file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I have a python code with some print statements.Now, I want to read input from one file and output it to another file.How do i do it ?
Should i include this ?

**code** :

```
fo = open("foo.txt", "r")
foo = open("out.txt","w")
```

Comment: No, you should use the context manager; `with open("foo.txt") as fo, open("out.txt", "w") as foo:`

Comment: You should read some tutorials about python programming. But as a start, check out [shutil](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html).

Comment: print inside out.txt using foo.write()? @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naive way:

```
fo = open("foo.txt", "r")
foo = open("out.txt","w")
foo.write(fo.read())
fo.close()
foo.close()
```

Better way, using [with](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm):

```
with open("foo.txt", "r") as fo:
    with open("out.txt", "w") as foo:
        foo.write(fo.read())
```

Nice way (using a module that does it for you - [shutil.copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy)):

```
from shutil import copy
copy("foo.txt", "out.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
with open("foo.txt", "r") as fo, open("out.txt", "w") as foo:
    foo.write(fo.read())
```